# We now have a Chat Room to discus the Topic of the Fortnight!

Tags: discussion, chat

[Here](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/5911/topic-of-the-fortnight) is where you can join in the discussion. Let me know your thoughts on the chat!

Comment: Just a quick FYI for Americans or others who might not know -- a fortnight is two weeks. :)

Comment: Community♦ picked an odd question to bump this time.

Answer (score 1):

There will be a discussion about the Topic being picked for the period 1-14 october on the 29th of this month. Let me know if there is a preferred time, otherwise I'll hold one at [7PM UTC](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=7%20pm%2029/09/12%20utc%20in%20america) and one later on in America.